# Splicing strings out of a long reference string given their coordinates in that reference string

Tags: r, string, subset, splice

Although this is a `genomics` question, since it's dealing with splicing (getting subsets) of strings I think it's relevant for this audience rather to `Bioconductor` alone.

Pretty simple, I have a list of long strings (chromosomes of the genome). For example, I create and store 10 chromosomes using the `Bioconductor` `Biostrings` package:

```
set.seed(1)
set <- NULL
for (i in 1:10) set <- c(set,paste(sample(Biostrings::DNA_ALPHABET[1:4],10000,replace=T),collapse=""))

genome.set <- Biostrings::DNAStringSet(set)
names(genome.set) <- paste0("chr",1:10)
```

And then I have a `data.frame` of transcript coordinates (from a `GTF` file), where each transcript can have multiple lines:

```
library(dplyr)
gtf.df <- data.frame(seqnames = sample(names(genome.set),100,replace=T),
                     strand = sample(c("+","-"),100,replace=T),
                     start = sample(1:9000,100,replace=F)) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(end = start+sample(1:1000,100,replace = F))

gtf.df <- gtf.df %>% dplyr::group_by(seqnames) %>%
  dplyr::arrange(start,end) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(transcript_id = paste0(seqnames,"_",sample(1:8,length(seqnames),replace=T))) %>%
  dplyr::ungroup()
```

And what I want to do is for each transcript join its sequences by splicing them out from `genome.set`.

Using the `Biostrings` again I achieve this this way:

```
transcript_ids <- unique(gtf.df$transcript_id)
transcript.seqs <- sapply(1:length(transcript_ids),function(t){
  transcript.gtf.df <- gtf.df %>% dplyr::filter(gtf.df$transcript_id == transcript_ids[t])
  transcript.seq <- paste(sapply(1:nrow(transcript.gtf.df),function(e)
    unname(as.character(Biostrings::subseq(genome.set[which(names(genome.set) == transcript.gtf.df$seqnames[1])],start=transcript.gtf.df$start[e],end=transcript.gtf.df$end[e])))
  ),collapse="")
  if(transcript.gtf.df$strand[1] == "-") transcript.seq <- unname(as.character(Biostrings::reverseComplement(Biostrings::DNAString(transcript.seq))))
  return(transcript.seq)
})
```

My problem is that I have `4520919` transcripts in my real data and the last part takes a long while. So my question is if and how this can be done faster, either using `Biostrings` or any other way.

Comment: Is `transcript.gtf.df$seqnames[1]` supposed to be indexed `1` or `e` in the second `sapply` ?

Comment: `transcript_id` has the same `seqnames` across all its lines in the `gtf.df` so I'm just grabbing the first one using `transcript.gtf.df$seqnames[1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have rewritten your `sapply` methods with two major changes:

- Firstly, I used `vapply` which in general is quite faster
- Secondly, I used a lot of `.subset2` to subset data frames

**Edit**

- I have managed to get rid of the inner loop (`vapply`)
- Substituted the function `Biostrings::reverseComplement`

Here is the code

```
names_genome.set <- names(genome.set)
transcript_ids <- unique(gtf.df$transcript_id)
transcript_seqs <- vapply(seq_along(transcript_ids), function (t) {
  ind_id <- which(.subset2(gtf.df, 5L) == transcript_ids[t])
  x <- unname(as.character(genome.set[names_genome.set == .subset2(gtf.df, 1L)[ind_id[1L]]]))
  out <- paste0(substring(text = x, first = .subset2(gtf.df, 3L)[ind_id], last = .subset2(gtf.df, 4L)[ind_id]), collapse = '')
  if (.subset2(gtf.df, 2L)[ind_id[1L]] == '-') {
    out <- unlist(strsplit(out, ''))
    ind_A <- out == 'A'
    ind_T <- out == 'T'
    ind_C <- out == 'C'
    ind_G <- out == 'G'
    out[ind_A] <- 'C'
    out[ind_T] <- 'G'
    out[ind_G] <- 'T'
    out[ind_C] <- 'A'
    out <- paste(out, collapse = '')
  }
  out
}, character(1))
```

Here are some benchmarking figures with the sample data provided

```
# Unit: milliseconds
#       expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval cld
#     sapply 160.94296 169.97698 180.13836 175.20474 182.58224 400.3273   100   c
# vapply_old  66.20113  69.59185  72.96804  71.45861  74.56051 120.0023   100  b 
# vapply_new  47.45224  49.51573  52.87001  50.97023  54.52104 109.3320   100 a  

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  'sapply' = {
    transcript.seqs <- sapply(1:length(transcript_ids),function(t){
      transcript.gtf.df <- gtf.df %>% dplyr::filter(gtf.df$transcript_id == transcript_ids[t])
      transcript.seq <- paste(sapply(1:nrow(transcript.gtf.df),function(e)
        unname(as.character(Biostrings::subseq(genome.set[which(names(genome.set) == transcript.gtf.df$seqnames[1])],start=transcript.gtf.df$start[e],end=transcript.gtf.df$end[e])))
      ),collapse="")
      if(transcript.gtf.df$strand[1] == "-") transcript.seq <- unname(as.character(Biostrings::reverseComplement(Biostrings::DNAString(transcript.seq))))
      return(transcript.seq)
    })
  },
  'vapply_old' = {
    transcript_seqs <- vapply(seq_along(transcript_ids), function (t) {
      ind_id <- which(.subset2(gtf.df, 5L) == transcript_ids[t])
      x <- unname(as.character(genome.set[names_genome.set == .subset2(gtf.df, 1L)[ind_id[1L]]]))
      out <- vapply(ind_id, 
                    function (e) substr(x = x, start = .subset2(gtf.df, 3L)[e], stop = .subset2(gtf.df, 4L)[e]),
                    character(1))
      out <- paste(out, collapse = '')
      if (.subset2(gtf.df, 2L)[ind_id[1L]] == '-') {
        out <- unname(as.character(Biostrings::reverseComplement(Biostrings::DNAString(out))))
      }
      out
    }, character(1))
  },
  'vapply_new' = {
    transcript_seqs <- vapply(seq_along(transcript_ids), function (t) {
      ind_id <- which(.subset2(gtf.df, 5L) == transcript_ids[t])
      x <- unname(as.character(genome.set[names_genome.set == .subset2(gtf.df, 1L)[ind_id[1L]]]))
      out <- paste0(substring(text = x, first = .subset2(gtf.df, 3L)[ind_id], last = .subset2(gtf.df, 4L)[ind_id]), collapse = '')
      if (.subset2(gtf.df, 2L)[ind_id[1L]] == '-') {
        out <- unlist(strsplit(out, ''))
        ind_A <- out == 'A'
        ind_T <- out == 'T'
        ind_C <- out == 'C'
        ind_G <- out == 'G'
        out[ind_A] <- 'C'
        out[ind_T] <- 'G'
        out[ind_G] <- 'T'
        out[ind_C] <- 'A'
        out <- paste(out, collapse = '')
      }
      out
    }, character(1))
  }
)
```

I will try to to find ways to enhance it still (there might be vectorization possible). <s>I haven't grasped yet what the function `reverseComplement` does for instance - maybe that can be performed more efficiently.</s>

You can try with larger data sets and see if there is an improvement. Also, `Rcpp` might be an idea here if efficiency really is at stake.

Comment: Thanks a lot @nate. `reverseComplement` is a bit more specific to DNA. Each chromosome in `genome.set` actually has a pair that I've left out, which is its reverse complement, which means that the order of the string is reversed and all `C`'s are replaced by `G`'s and vice versa, and all `A`'s are replaced by `T`'s and vice versa. The `strand` column in `gtf.df` determines this, as the code suggests. So rather than keeping a reverse complement for each chromosome I can do this on the spliced sequence.

Comment: @dan Alright, I've edited my code with a substitution for `Biostrings::reverseComplement`. It performs significantly better now. (You should check that substitution at any rate - I don't know the first thing about biology haha)